# Error while creating own spec git public repository pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to create my own pods following [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-your-first-cocoapod--cms-24332)

However when I added my code to the pods project and tried to push it. Then I get following error -

> ERROR | xcodebuild:  /Users/klouddata/Documents/Developer/MyPods/Classes/PDRatingsView.m:87:44: error: no visible @interface for 'UIApplication' declares the selector 'openURL:options:completionHandler:

I dont understand how to solve this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To push pods your repo can't have errors (I believe it can't even have warnings). If error doesn't exist during building your framework then pods build it differently (maybe with different swift version?). To set swift version during pods building use command (found on pods website but didn't try it)

```
echo "3.0" > .swift-version
```

Personally  I used following command (which is "bad way")

```
export TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3
```

Comment: Thanks Adamsor , but I am using Objective C and error that I am getting is running on sample project ..what i want to do is  ... add my class to public repository so that i can install the pods for it ..

Answer (score 0):

without understanding the problem somebody given the negative marks to this question,
Any ways after long research i found the answer myself.
As mentioned in ERROR | xcodebuild:, path for xcode build is different as i have in my system old xcode installed so need to change the path and I've to run both Xcode 7 (to build old version) and Xcode 8 (to build current develop branch)

using following command

launchctl remove com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService || true